# Bridge / Tunnel using netcat and named pipes

Tags: netcat, udp

I have two devices (A and B) that should communicate with each other - indirectly via a server (S):

```
/---\       /---\       /---\
| A | <===> | S | <===> | B |
\---/       \---/       \---/
```

A and B can connect, disconnect and reconnect independently from each other to S.

My approach is to use named pipes as buffers and two instances of netcat who open a port for A and B, respectively, store received contents into one pipe and send back the contents of the other pipe.

I use the following commands to get it running:

```
mkfifo a2b
mkfifo b2a
nc -n -u -lkvp 5050 < b2a | tee a2b &
nc -n -u -lkvp 5051 < a2b | tee b2a &
```

Explanation of the options:

- `-n`: Avoid problems with unavailable nameserver
- `-u`: use UDP
- `-l`: start listening
- `-k`: keep open after disconnect
- `-v`: verbose
- `| tee fifo`: output received characters to stdout and write them into `fifo`

When I connect with A to `S:5050` and with B to `S:5051` (e.g. using `nc -uv S 5050` for A) and send some characters, they are displayed on the output of S, but not received by B (and vice versa).

What am I doing wrong?

And what's the correct term for what I am trying to achieve - is it bridging, tunneling, forwarding, relaying?

Comment: looks like netcat can't handle correctly the "keep open" mode and UDP: try again without -k. As you probably want the -k feature, that won't solve your problem anyway.

Comment: Thank you @A.B for pointing this out; I tried to omit the -u flag to use TCP instead and it works as expected now. UDP would be more appropiate in my usecase, TCP is acceptable though if it solves the problem.
I'll leave the question open though, because I still don't understand why my original approach does not work.

Comment: I'd recommand to replace netcat with socat (which can work somewhat), but then there's still the problem of not detecting udp is closed (or rather not used anymore). It's automatic for tcp. In my tests it was working except it left dangling socats for each new fresh connection from client (where the source udp port changes).